# Inputbox does not return the entered value

Tags: excel, vba

When i am running the following code below (only a part of the full code), and for instant writing the value "0,9", then the inputbox returns "89,9999976158142%" in excel.

Further, when i later in the code has another where the user is supposed to choose between "Pipeline, Ordre, tilbud, afsluttet and tabt", then in excel it returns the same value as where written for the procent, "89,9999976158142%", instead of some of the options??**

```
Procent = InputBox("Indtast procent : (0 - 0,10 -0,25 - 0,50 - 0,75 - 0,90 - 1", "procent")

    If Procent = "0" Or Procent = "0,10" Or Procent = "0,25" Or Procent = "0,5" Or Procent = "0,75" Or Procent = "0,9" Or Procent = "1" Then
        GoTo videre2
            Else
Videre5:
            MsgBox "mistake"
        Procent = InputBox("Indtast Procent : (0 - 0,10 -0,25 - 0,50 - 0,75 - 0,90 - 1", "Procent ")
                If Procent = "0" Or Procent = "0,10" Or Procent = "0,25" Or Procent = "0,5" Or Procent = "0,75" Or Procent = "0,9" Or Procent = "1" Then
            GoTo videre2
        Else: GoTo Videre5
    End If
    End If
    
videre2:
Cells(Lastrow, "E").Value = Procent 



Kategori = InputBox("Indtast Kategori: Pipeline - Ordre - Tilbud - Afsluttet - Tabt", "Kategori")
'Cells(Lastrow, "I").Value = Kategori
     If Kategori = "Pipeline" Or Kategori = "Ordre" Or Kategori = "Tilbud" Or Kategori = "Afsluttet" Or Kategori = "Tabt" Then
        GoTo videre3
            Else
Videre6:
            MsgBox "Stavefejl"
        Kategori = InputBox("Indtast Kategori: Pipeline - Ordre - Tilbud - Afsluttet - Tabt", "Kategori")
            If Kategori = "Pipeline" Or Kategori = "Ordre" Or Kategori = "Tilbud" Or Kategori = "Afsluttet" Or Kategori = "Tabt" Then
            GoTo videre3
        Else: GoTo Videre6
    End If
    End If
    
videre3:
Cells(Lastrow, "I").Value = Sandsynlighed
```

**I can not find the mistake??**

Comment: Is the cell where the "Procent" is written to formatted as Percentage?  If you change the number format type, what happens to the result?

Comment: What type is `Procent` in your VBA code? If it is  a `Single`, you will have only about 7 or 8 significant digits, try changing it to a `Double`, i.e. `Dim Procent as Double`

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel for discussion of numerical precision in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't provide some important informations.

a) If you enter 0.9 into a cell that is formatted as Percentage, it is shown as 90%, so I assume that your cell *is* formatted as Percentage. If you really want 0.9%, divide the value by 100 before writing it to the cell.

b) Obviously, you have an rounding problem. You don't show how the variable `Procent` is declared, but I assume that you have declared it as `Single`. This is bad for 2 reasons: You will get rounding errors, and you will get a runtime error if something non-numeric is entered. Declare the variable as String or Variant and after checking for validity, convert it to Double (not to Single).

c) According to the code you show, you write the second answer into variable `Kategori`, but you assign the variable `Sandsynlighed` to the cell.

d) Your code could be improved. Avoid `GoTo` and avoid to duplicate the input and check statements. One idea could be:

```
Do While True
    Dim Procent As Variant
    Procent = InputBox("Indtast procent : (0 - 0,10 -0,25 - 0,50 - 0,75 - 0,90 - 1", "procent")
    If Procent = "0" Or Procent = "0,10" Or Procent = "0,25" Or Procent = "0,5" Or Procent = "0,75" Or Procent = "0,9" Or Procent = "1" Then Exit Do
Loop
Cells(lastRow, "E").Value = CDbl(Procent) ' (or maybe CDbl(Procent) / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind, that an *InputBox* always returns text. Thus, this must be converted to numeric for a test, and - as you use comma as the *decimal separator* - the Cxxx functions must be used.

Also, what you see it floating point errors, which you can avoid by using *Decimal* or *Currency*. So, follow a route like this:

```vb
Public Function CheckPercent()

    Const Prompt    As String = "Indtast procent: 0 - 0,10 - 0,25 - 0,50 - 0,75 - 0,90 - 1"
    Const Title     As String = "Procent"
    
    Dim Text        As String
    Dim Procent     As Currency
    Dim Continue    As Boolean
    
    Text = InputBox(Prompt, Title)
    If IsNumeric(Text) Then
        Procent = CCur(Text)
        Select Case Procent
            Case 0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1
                Continue = True
        End Select        
    End If
    
    If Continue = False Then
        ' Try again - or other option
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Continue:", Continue
    
    ' <snip>
    
End Function
```